# Create a mysql event with laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Is there any way to create a mysql event using laravel migration? If yes how?

Comment: You can try `DB::statement('CREATE EVENT....');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DB::statement()`. More details [here](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_statement).

```
DB::statement('CREATE EVENT my_event ...')
```

Comment: You have to use `DB::unprepared` like @JinIzzraeel mentioned. Else, you get an error like `Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use DB::statement(''), as the event creation needs to be on unprepared mode.
Use the following:

DB::unprepared('Your event creation code goes here')

Comment: Still we can use `DB::statement` if we are using configuration `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true`; I always enable this because emulated prepared statements are safe enough in modern PHP versions.

Answer (score 1):

> DB::unprepared("
>           CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS delete_etiqueta_rendimento_pack
>               ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
>                   STARTS '2020-04-21 01:00:27' 
>               ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
>                   COMMENT 'Deletes all record redimento_pack from 3 months ago' 
>               DO 
>                   BEGIN
>                       DELETE
>                           FROM rendimento_packing
>                       WHERE data_hora < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH);
>               END
>           ");

If you use DB::statement('') probabli you gonne a see this error:
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query 
buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute.