# MYSQL CREATE EVENT with laravel DB::statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8

This question relates to Laravels DB::statement function handling of MySQL querys with PHP variable bindings and not PHP's PDO binding process as found in the possible duplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20585535/sqlstatehy093-invalid-parameter-number-number-of-bound-variables-does-not-ma). PDO is used in the backend by Laravel eloquent but the structure of DB::statement function differs from the way you do it in the PDO method.

I am attempting to have my controller's store function create a mysql event when an entry is saved to the database. When the form is submitted, Laravel is throwing the error

*'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens (SQL: CREATE EVENT test ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE DO UPDATE pagers SET escalation_level = escalation_level + 1 WHERE id = :issue)'.*

I am attempting to recreate the following MySQL query

```
CREATE EVENT test ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE DO UPDATE issues SET escalation_level = escalation_level + 1 WHERE id = 'Rd8409347-70bb-4e3e-b351-b49c10ce9a2a';
```

To me it seems that I have 1 variable in the query and then 1 variable passed by the array, so I cant seem to get the query to succeed. Below is the controller that the form submits to.
Thank you for your help.

**IssueController.php**

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    //Validate Input
    $request->validate([
       'company_id' => 'string|max:255',
       'message' => 'required|string|max:255' 
    ]);

    //Once the form input has passed validation add input to the database

    $issueData = new Issue();
    $issueData->id = "R" . Uuid::generate(4)->string;
    $issueData->company_id = $request->company_id;
    $issueData->first_name = Auth::user()->first_name;
    $issueData->last_name = Auth::user()->last_name;
    $issueData->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $issueData->message = $request->message;


    //Create MySQL event to increment escalation level
    //Event will be named equal to the new page 'R' ID
    //That has just been generated.

    DB::statement('CREATE EVENT test ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE DO UPDATE issues SET escalation_level = escalation_level + 1 WHERE id = :issue_id', array('issue_id' => $issueData->id));

    $issueData->save();

    return redirect('home')->with('status', ['Message sent successfully.', 
        'You can monitor the status of your message from Check Status section']);

}
```

Comment: @Jay that does not seem to be a valid duplicate. OP are posting the values to be bound, and make a somewhat eloquent reasoning about this. Not to say that there isn't a laravel specific dupe on this site, but the general PDO one does not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue with the help of the SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554497/create-a-mysql-event-with-laravel-migration). Some queries in Laravel require the use of unprepared statements.  I was able to resolve the issues by using DB::unprepared like this:

```
        DB::unprepared('CREATE EVENT event_name ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE DO UPDATE issues SET escalation_level = escalation_level + 1 WHERE id = ' . '/'' . $issueData->id . '/'');
```